# Highstock solid gauge stops

Tags: highcharts

Solid gauge stop colors don't seem to be working when substituting out highstock for highcharts.

```
 yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
```

See the following jsfiddle to toggle between the two: http://jsfiddle.net/6orc2vou/1/

Comment: It is a bug. It does not work in Highcharts 5.0.4+ in general. Use 5.0.3 version or the latest github version http://jsfiddle.net/qvL4twbf/1/